# Product .exe does not start if # is in folder name

Tags: java, eclipse, export, product

I was wondering if there is a specific reason, why my eclipse product .exe does not start, if the parent directory of the exe-file contains a `#`.
I am using Windows XP (SP3) and exported my eclipse application. The resulting .exe file saluts me with the following screen:

[image]
<sub>(source: [iachelini.de](http://www.iachelini.de/rcsd/wtf.jpg))</sub>

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a guess.

The launcher is implemented in a way that the command line options are interpreted by a batch script ... and the `#` is interpreted as the beginning of a line comment.

**Edit:**

The 'eclipse.exe' loads the 'eclipse.ini'. Here you can make comments with a `#` at the beginning of the line. This does not prove that eclipse uses a batch script for loading (to be sure one should look at the source), but it is an hint that the comment-assumption is valid.

Comment: Is eclipse really using a "batch script" to parse the parameters?

Comment: I'd love to look at the source, but can only find EclipseLazyStarter, of which I doubt is used when launching the product.exe

Comment: http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/platform-launcher/library/eclipse.c?revision=HEAD

Comment: Thanks Arne, very kind.
But I doubt I have the passion to crawl through all this _tcslen-galore to determine path and location. I assume one of those str-finder reacts allergic towards #.
Thank you very much for your feedback. Appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

My first guess was wrong. The problem has nothing to do with comments or a batch script. It's a bug in the java code of eclipse. I have filled a bug report:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=320732